# PHP script - unexpected '}

Tags: php

This script is displaying the data I requested (Id,Dsc,School) but im getting error on line 20.

```
{
  if ($row['suspended']==1){
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp\www\unit5\scripts\meminclude.php on line 20

```
   <?php
 include("dbconnect1.php");

$query = "SELECT id,dsc, school FROM module WHERE dsc LIKE '%%%s%%'";

$link = @ mysql_query($query);
  if (!$link) {

header("location:../account/account.master.php?page=invalid&errorcode=1");
   die();
 }

$i=0;
 $status="";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($link, MYSQL_ASSOC))


{
  if ($row['suspended']==1){


$status="SUS";
  }
   echo "

<tr id='row$i' class='trows'>".
         "
<td id='id$i'>".$row['id']."</td>".
         "
<td id='dsc$i'>".$row['dsc']."</td>".
         "
<td id='school$i'>".$row['school']."</td>".
         "
</td>".
         "
<td><input type='radio' name='whome' id='showMe$i' onclick='showMem($i)' /></td>
";
         if ($status=='SUS'){
          echo "
<td><input type='radio' name='suspend' checked='checked' disabled='disabled' /></td>
";
         } else {
          echo "
<td><input type='radio' name='suspend' id='suspend$i' onclick='suspendMem($i)' /></td>
";
         }
         echo "
<td><input type='radio' name='delete' id='delete$i' onclick='deleteMe($i)' /></td>
".
         "
<td id='status$i'>".$status."</td></tr>";
  $i++;
  $status="";
 }
?>
```

The script is referenced here:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
           var numrecs=$(".trows").length;
           var me= $('#th1').html()+" - "+(numrecs)+" Records in Table.";
           $('#th1').html(me);
           RiVm=numrecs;
      });
     </script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/results.css" type="text/css" /> 
     <div id="appleft">
         <form id="myapprovelist" method="post"> 
         <fieldset style="border:none">
         <table id="myTable"> 
          <tr><th id="th1" colspan="10">Active Membership List</th></tr>
          <tr class="red"> 
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>DSC</th>
           <th>School</th>
           </tr>
          <?php include("../scripts/meminclude.php")?>  
         </table> 
        </fieldset>
       </form>
      </div>
      <div id="appright">
       <img id="theBroon" src="" alt="" /><br />
       <span id="myBroon"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both">    
    </div>
```

Comment: You should fix trivial parse errors on your own, not open up topics like this to sort these errors.

Comment: It looks OK, paste `dbconnect1.php` code.

Comment: the showMem($i) is change to showMem({$i})

Comment: @RajMohan - what you suggested makes no sense and is in no way related to the parse error, nothing changes by adding braces to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I went through and cleaned up the formatting, indentation and changed a WHOLE HEAP of quotes.

Try this:

```
<?php
    include("dbconnect1.php");
    $query = "SELECT id,dsc, school FROM module WHERE dsc LIKE '%%%s%%'";
    $link = @ mysql_query($query);
    if (!$link) 
    {
        header("location:../account/account.master.php?page=invalid&errorcode=1");
        die();
    }

    $i=0;
    $status="";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($link, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        if ($row['suspended']==1)
        {
            $status="SUS";
        }
        echo "<tr id='row".$i."' class='trows'><td id='id".$i."'>".$row['id']."</td><td id='dsc".$i."'>".$row['dsc']."</td><td id='school".$i."'>".$row['school']."</td></td><td><input type='radio' name='whome' id='showMe".$i."' onclick='showMem(".$i.")' /></td>";
        if ($status=='SUS')
        {
            echo "<td><input type='radio' name='suspend' checked='checked' disabled='disabled' /></td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td><input type='radio' name='suspend' id='suspend".$i."' onclick='suspendMem(".$i.")' /></td>";
        }
        echo "<td><input type='radio' name='delete' id='delete".$i."' onclick='deleteMe(".$i.")' /></td><td id='status".$i."'>".$status."</td></tr>";
        $i++;
        $status="";
    }
?>
```

and dbconnect:

```
<?php 
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbase = "timetable";
    $link = @ mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    if (!$link) 
    {
        header("location:../account/account.master.php?page=invalid&errorcode=1");
        die($link);
    }
    $db_selected = @ mysql_select_db($dbase, $link);
    if (!$db_selected) 
    {
        header("location:../account/account.master.php?page=invalid&errorcode=1");
        die();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for doing that but it made no difference

Comment: The script is also referenced in here:

Comment: I don't think you link worked there chap, can you edit your question to include your whole code? The spare bracket must be somewhere else.

Comment: Can you include the PHP code from the code that creates the third set of code in your question?

Comment: I'm sorry this is for a uni project and my knowledge is not very good, I thought I sent you it all

Comment: The code that includes the line: `<?php include("../scripts/meminclude.php")?>  ` Is that the only PHP in that page? If not, can you post the rest of the PHP in it?

Comment: I can't see anything in the code that is a spare curly mate. I have eyeballed the code I gave you a number of times, there are no unopened curlies left there, but if the engine is giving you an error, there must be some PHP code outside what you have posted.

Comment: All I can suggest is use something like [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/?sortBy=date) to edit your code. It will show you right off the bar where your errors are.